# Deleting a document by using given any field and vlue

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb and I need to delete a document in a collection using given field and it's value. I have a collection called customers ad it contains documents with id, firstname, lastname, email, age, address. I need to delete a document using any filed such as `firstName = "Dave"` or `email="dave@email.com"` or using any given field. I have searched this in online articles but I was unable to find the correct query. Can anybody please help me to do this?

Comment: You should check the documentation well before asking a question or cross check if such questions exist with a solution. Go here to read about MongoDB `remove`, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following way to delete a doc from mongodb. Here is the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)

```
>db.COLLECTION_NAME.remove(DELLETION_CRITTERIA)
```

Following is the example:

Let's say you have the following 3 documents in your collection named `mycol`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec5), "firstName":"Dave"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec6), "firstName":"Bob"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec7), "firstName":"Alice"}
```

You can remove the doc like this:

```
>db.mycol.remove({'firstName':'Dave'})
>db.mycol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec6), "firstName":"Bob"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec7), "firstName":"Alice"}
>
```

Comment: Thank you for ur help. I need a generic way to do this. Instead of calling "firstName" : "Dave"  in db.mycol.remove({'firstName':'Dave'}) I need something like db.mycol.remove({'genericName':'genericValue'}). we shouldn't be able to modify this fieldName and values we pass. I can have only one remove query which accept any value for fieldName and the value

Comment: yeah, you can create a function which takes fieldName & value as an argument, and then in the code, pass on that `"fieldName":"value"` in the query. It should work then.